# Deploying ColdFusion in JBoss -- getting the right root path

Tags: apache, coldfusion, jboss, jboss5.x

We're deploying multiple ColdFusion 9 instances (one per virtual host) on a JBoss server and I'm having trouble getting the correct path back from ColdFusion's internal functions. Specifically, the context seems to be rooted two directories too high. For example, if we do something like #CGI.SCRIPT_NAME#, we'd get "index.cfm" previously, but since moving to JBoss, we get "foo.bar.edu/htdocs/index.cfm".

I've been told that this is an intractable problem, but I find that hard to believe. I'm looking into the jboss-web.xml file's  parameter, but I haven't yet determined what that should be. Anyone have experience with this?

I've tried a CF mapping, but that doesn't work because the path has periods in it, which CF won't accept. Seems there should be a simple way to handle this.

We're using JBoss 5, Apache 2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP proxying using Apache IS going to change some of the CGI variables. It's a fact.

Using AJP instead will fix most of said issues but there's still a few that get caught up in the proxy, and if you are using a context root then even more so.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: we are using AJP.